# Kendo custom widget with MVVM and init event - how?

Tags: events, mvvm, kendo-ui, widget, initialization

I try to implement a custom kendo widget with "Init" event. If the widget is initialized with JavaScript, the event is triggered. But when the widget is initialized with data attributes - it doesn't. What do I miss?

Sample: http://dojo.telerik.com/UQoWi

Note: As you can see, I've tried to handle the "init" event according to the KendoUI's documentation:

```
... data-init="onInit" data-bind="events: { init: onInit }" ...
```

Comment: This has been a while but I'm wondering if you ever solved this as I have the same question.

Comment: No, I didn't solve it. Maybe the guys from Telerik should be notified.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. I went through their code and can't see where data-init is ever referenced. However, there is a binding that might work just as well. We can bind to data-bind="events: { dataBinding: onBinding, dataBinded: onBound }" and it's invoked when the data source is being set and then when it's done. Which coincidently happens during construction for HTML created widgets. Hope this helps you! Also, I found it allows the attribute namespace to be changed thus allowing it to work with Knockout. kendo.ns="kendo-" makes data-kendo-bind="" work. I'll turn this into a answer.

Comment: "init" event is my custom event which I raise upon widget initialization. I think that "dataBinding" and "dataBound" events should be raised when the widget's bound data is going to be changed or was changed. So my idea is to trigger "init" event just once - upon widget initialization and then optionally to trigger "dataBinding" and "dataBound" events each time the bound data is changed. For example if we take a kendoDropDownList and set "autoBind" option to "false" you will see that the widget is initialized, but until you open the dropdown the "dataBound" event won't be raised.

Comment: Check out my answer as it does what you described you wanted it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppliment: I'd like to add that i completely understand WHY there is not an init binder already. It doesn't really make sense. As a ViewModel can be BOUND to many different things in Kendo, an init callback inside a Viewmodel for a Widget just doesn't make sense. That's why the dataBinding and dataBound is used. When the widget is created it DOES invoke the handler for data-init="", it just has to be in scope. That's the one time call for a widget. The ViewModel Observable can be bound and unbound to many different widgets. How would the system know that the Observable ViewModel is supposed to be strictly tied to that one specific widget? It wouldn't unless you update the Widget to had an internal data source and observable.

If this Observable is bound to multiple of your custom widgets, the onInit will be called for each widget. It will not be called for any of the built in widgets as they don't trigger(INIT). That's easily fixed by overloading the fn.init function, or extending them. Or, even creating a global onInit function that is used in the `data-init` element attribute, since you can get access to the widget itself through the parameters. `$(element).data("kendoWidget")` etc.

Hope this helps! It's certainly helped me understand everything.

---

I've been able to do what you want. It seems I was greatly mistaken about what the `data-bind="events: {}"` is for. The handlers within that definition appear to be handlers for the HTML events. So we can add a new 'init' handler to the Widget system itself. I've been able to get your example to work with the following code below.

The key is to add a NEW binder for a Kendo Event called 'init'.

```
kendo.data.binders.widget.init = 
   kendo.data.Binder.extend({
      function(widget, bindings, options) {
        Binder.fn.init.call(this, widget.element[0], bindings, options);
        this.widget = widget;
      },
      refresh: function () {
         var init = this.bindings.init.get();
      }              
   });
```

Then we can use the `data-bind="init: onInitFromMVVM"` to bind to a one time even call. This will only be a one time call because it's only triggered in the init of the Widget.

I went through the source code over and over and the `events: {}` confused me until I started reading the documentation. Then I realized that almost all the handlers inside `events: {}` were for HTML events. Things like visible, onmouseover, onmouseexit, etc. So I then created a new binder called 'init', and your code worked after that.

The code below produces the following output: 
`widget init proof`
`global init proof`
`init mvvm proof`

It even calls the handler for `data-init` in the global scope.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled</title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>    
    <script>          
      var binders = kendo.data.binders,
                Binder  = kendo.data.Binder,
                proxy   = $.proxy,
                    ui        = kendo.ui,
                    Widget  = ui.Widget,
                    INIT        = 'init';

        (function ($) {

            kendo.data.binders.widget.init = 
              kendo.data.Binder.extend({
                init: function(widget, bindings, options) {
                                        Binder.fn.init.call(this, widget.element[0], bindings, options);
                    this.widget = widget;
                },

                refresh: function () {
                    var init = this.bindings.init.get();
                }              
            });

            var MyWidget = Widget.extend({
                options: {
                    name: 'MyWidget',
                },
                events: [
                    INIT
                ],
                init: function (element, options) {                  
                    var that = this;
                    console.log('widget init proof');  
                    Widget.fn.init.call(this, element, options);                                                             
                    that.trigger(INIT);
                }
            });

            ui.plugin(MyWidget);

        })(jQuery);

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var observableModel = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
                onInitVM: function (e, opts) {
                    console.log('init mvvm proof');
                }
            });

            kendo.bind($('#myWidgetMVVM'), observableModel);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Open console...</div>
    <input type="hidden" id="myWidgetMVVM" data-init="onInit" data-role="mywidget" data-bind="init: onInitVM" />
  <script>
    function onInit(element, options) {
       console.log("global init proof");       
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK, this sounds logical!